# Angular 2 router : outlet

Tags: angular

I have an app with a `main component` and a `child component`. By this I mean that the `directive` for the `child component` is embedded into the template of the `parent`. I added a `router` to this with the intention of putting the navigation in a second `child component` (for now it is in the template of the `main component`).

Anyway if I precise the outlet for the routes by adding an `outlet` property to my route configs, I get an error:

> "cannot match any route".

**Edit :** https://plnkr.co/edit/S9Fw3UdTK4p3MdR993Gu Doesn't run but displays the code. This version works, if I give a name to the outlet and reference it in the routes configuration, it doesn't work anymore (producing the said error).

**Update :** Not sure if it's relevant but I've discovered that relative paths in `routerLink`s for `child components` are not "refreshed" at URL change but only when the html element they're linked to are refreshed. Thus if the navigation for your `child components` is not inside your parent `router-outlet`, you're screwed.

Also I get parentheses around the "child segments" of my URLs for some reason. Even stranger, if I navigate manually (by entering the URL manually) to a `child component`, and then navigate between `child components` only, without going to a `parent component` or to the default `child component` I don't get the parentheses.

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you tried. Can you reproduce in https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html ?

Comment: I just read that imperative routing might work. I don't know what that is, I will do some research. Still, I don't see why it wouldn't (or at least shouldn't) work like that

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem too!